# "Tone" vs. "shade"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, writing

- "Tone" and "shade" seem to refer to the darkness or brightness of a thing.  So do they mean the same thing? Where is it proper to use each of them?
- When describing a person's skin, what is the difference between light-toned (as opposed to dark-toned and medium-toned)  and fair-complected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the field of design, every color has what are called *tints* and *shades*. A *tint* of a basic color is a lighter version of that color, and a *shade* is a darker version. *Tone* is a general term to describe the lightness or darkness (tint or shade) of a basic color.

> The painting was a study done in dark tones, burnt umber and brick red, with shades of orange and olive. Here and there tints of those colors were used as accents.

Answer (score 3):

[*Tone*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tone) and [*shade*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/shade) are two words with two different meanings. You cannot always replace *tone* with *shade*.

1. *Tone* refers to musical or vocal sounds, while *shade* only refers to colors.

   > The piano tone appears monochrome or lacking in warmth.
2. *Tone* also means:

   - The normal level of firmness or slight contraction in a resting muscle
   - The general effect of color or of light and shade in a picture
   - A slight degree of difference in the intensity of a color
3. *Shade* can mean:

   - Darkness and coolness caused by shelter from direct sunlight
   - A position of relative inferiority or obscurity
   - A color, especially with regard to how light or dark it is or as distinguished from one nearly like it
   - A slight degree of difference between colors

   > This area will be in shade for much part of the day.

   > Her elegant pink and black ensemble would put most outfits in the shade.

   > Maria's eyes darkened in shade.

   [*Complected*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/complected) means *having a specified complexion*, where [*complexion*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/complexion) means *the natural color, texture, and appearance of a person's skin, especially of the face* (e.g. *an attractive girl with a pale complexion*); differently from the other terms you listed, *complected* doesn't make only reference to the skin color.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "complected doesn't make only reference to the skin color"? The "other terms" I "listed" are "shade" and "tone", and I think they don't "make only reference to the skin color", so are they not different from "complected"/"complexion" in this regard?

Comment: _Complexion_ makes reference to three distinct aspects of a skin: color, texture, and appearance. _Tone_ would just make reference to the skin color. Saying that a person's skin is dark-toned doesn't say anything about the texture of his/her skin (e.g, if it's smooth).

Comment: This answer is entirely wrong. [See here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Tint-tone-shade.svg/800px-Tint-tone-shade.svg). You could at least have googled the terms before answering.

Comment: @GustvandeWal Apart the fact it covers just a single meaning of _tone_ and _shade_, you don't need to google, when you read a dictionary. But if you insist with links, [tone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tone) and [shade](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/shade) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

- When referring to colours, *tone* and *shade* are pretty close in meaning to me. If I were to make a difference, I'd say that *shade* is more about the detailed nuance of the colour, while *tone* can describe broader differences. If you say “various shades of blue”, you could use “tones” here (it feels less natural to me, but it works). If you say “in tones of green and red”, you couldn't substitute “shades” in that example.
- One’s skin is *light-toned*, but the person is *fair-complected* (or *fair-complexioned*)